# creating conditional in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am new to JavaScript and I have created this condition to check if the season is `Autumn`, `Winter`, `Spring`, or `Summer`.

Here is my JavaScript code:

1. My question is how to make this in fewer lines of code
2. How to use both uppercase and lowercase in the same code for eg: `October` and `october`

   ```
    const seasonName = prompt('entere the month name')

    if (seasonName == 'september') {
    console.log("The Season is Autumn.")
    }
    else if (seasonName == 'october') {
    console.log("The Season is Autumn.")
    }
    else if (seasonName == 'november') {
    console.log("The Season is Autumn.")
    }
    else if (seasonName == 'december') {
    console.log("The Season is Winter.")
    }
    else if (seasonName == 'january') {
    console.log("The Season is Winter.")
    }
    else if (seasonName == 'february') {
    console.log("The Season is Winter.")
    }
    else if (seasonName == 'march') {
    console.log("The Season is Winter.")
    }
    else if (seasonName == 'april') {
    console.log("The Season is Spring.")
    }
    else if (seasonName == 'may') {
    console.log("The Season is Spring.")
    }
    else if (seasonName == 'june') {
    console.log("The Season is Summer.")
    }
    else if (seasonName == 'july') {
    console.log("The Season is Summer.")
    }
    else if (seasonName == 'august') {
    console.log("The Season is Summer.")
    }
   ```

Comment:  http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: ... and [MDN for String.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Answer (score 1):

I like to take the following approach:

```
const seasonsByMonth = {
   'january': 'winter',
   'february': 'winter',
   ' march': 'winter',
   'april': 'spring',
   ...
}
const seasonName = prompt('entere the month name');
console.log(`The Season is ${seasonsByMonth[seasonName.toLowerCase()]}.`)
```

Comment: I like this approach because it fits in nicely with the Functional Programming paradigm: convert values (from month to season), then do the side effect (logging) separately. I've used maps instead of `switch` many a time. On the other hand, if OP is just starting out to learn JS, he perhaps should get familiar with `switch` first.

Answer (score 0):

```
const seasonName = prompt('entere the month name')

const seasonNameLowercase = seasonName.toLowerCase();

 if (seasonNameLowercase == 'september') {
 console.log("The Season is Autumn.")
 }
 else if (seasonNameLowercase == 'october') {
 console.log("The Season is Autumn.")
 }
 else if (seasonNameLowercase == 'november') {
 console.log("The Season is Autumn.")
 }
 else if (seasonNameLowercase == 'december') {
 console.log("The Season is Winter.")
 }
 else if (seasonNameLowercase == 'january') {
 console.log("The Season is Winter.")
 }
 else if (seasonNameLowercase == 'february') {
 console.log("The Season is Winter.")
 }
 else if (seasonNameLowercase == 'march') {
 console.log("The Season is Winter.")
 }
 else if (seasonNameLowercase == 'april') {
 console.log("The Season is Spring.")
 }
 else if (seasonNameLowercase == 'may') {
 console.log("The Season is Spring.")
 }
 else if (seasonNameLowercase == 'june') {
 console.log("The Season is Summer.")
 }
 else if (seasonNameLowercase == 'july') {
 console.log("The Season is Summer.")
 }
 else if (seasonNameLowercase == 'august') {
 console.log("The Season is Summer.")
 }
```

Comment: can you simplify what are you saying and please answer  2 number problem

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `switch` statement. Code is like this:

```
switch(seasonName) {
    case "september":
    case "october":
    case "november":
        console.log("The Season is Autumn.");
        break;
    case "december":
    case "january":
    case "february":
        console.log("The Season is Winter.");
        break;
    case "march":
    case "april":
    case "may":
        console.log("The Season is Spring.");
        break;
    case "june":
    case "july":
    case "august":
        console.log("The Season is Summer.");
        break;
}
```

Comment: but I want both lower case and upper cases in the same code like  September and September

Comment: @PrateekSingh if you change the first line to `switch(seasonName.toLowerCase()) {`, this will work for all (letter) cases, since the `(switch) case` labels are all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign them as objects and use key value pairs to retrieve

```js
// add your months as objects
const seasonObj = {
Autumn: ["september", "october", "november", ],
Spring: ["april", "may"],
summer: ["june", "july", "august"],
Winter: ["december", "january", "february", "march"]
}

function getSeason(value) {
for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(seasonObj)) {
  if(val.includes(value))
  {
  return `the Season is ${key}`
  }
}
}
const result = getSeason("april");
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with fewer lines of code,

```js
 const seasonName = prompt('entere the month name')

 let obj = {
   'summer': ['august', 'july', 'june'],
   'spring': ['may', 'april'],
   'winder': ['march', 'february', 'january'],
   'autumn': ['september', 'october', 'november']
 }

 function findSeason(seasonName) {
   let result = 'Invalid Month Name'

   let keys = Object.keys(obj)

   for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
     for (let j = 0; j < obj[keys[i]].length; j++) {
       if (seasonName === obj[keys[i]][j]) {
         result = `The Season is ${keys[i]}`
       }

     }
   }

   return result
 }




 console.log(findSeason(seasonName.toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JavaScript built-in function 'includes' to check whether the string present in an array or not

```js
const winterMonthName = ['January', 'February', 'December', 'january', 'february', , 'december'];
const springMonthName = ['March', 'April', 'May', 'march', 'april', 'may']
const summerMonthName = ['June', 'July', 'August', 'june', 'july', 'august']
const autumnMonthName = ['September', 'October', 'November', 'september', 'october', 'november']
const type = 'July';

if(winterMonthName.includes(type)){
  console.log('The Season is Winter')
}
else if(springMonthName.includes(type)){
  console.log('The Season is Spring')
}
else if(summerMonthName.includes(type)){
  console.log('The Season is Summer')
}
else if(autumnMonthName.includes(type)){
  console.log('The Season is Winter')
}
else {
  console.log('You entered wrong')
}
```